# MS Exchange 2003 to Google Apps Migration Domain Verification

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange-2003, cname-record, g-suite, txt-record

My company just decided to move to Google Apps due to lots of technical issues with our Exchange 2003 server. I have just signed up for the free trial account for Google Apps and one of the first steps required is verifying domain ownership. It has something to do with adding a TXT record or CNAME to the DNS' control panel. I do not have the access of our domain's control panel so I will have it configured by our provider.

Question is will there be any conflict with our existing mail server if the TXT record or CNAME record gets added? Also, when the migration is finished, will Google apps and MS Exchange be able to run at the same time?

Which verification type do you also recommend: TXT, CNAME or both?

Comment: My recommendation - Upgrade to 2010 or 2013 far superior and far more stable.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the TXT or CNAME record is just a way to prove to Google that you really control the DNS for domain name you're trying to use. The thought process is: "We'll give you this unique string of bits to put in DNS, if it shows up then you must have control of that domain's DNS."

Either method is fine to use. Some DNS providers don't allow you to use one type of record, so the other is provided for those scenarios.

The record they have you create won't impact anything in your current email infrastructure. You're creating the record to prove control, not to make a functional change.